# installing Oracle Instantclient on Mac OS/X without setting environment variables?

Tags: oracle, macos, installation, instantclient

Oracle's instructions specify setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.  This makes my application dependent on random users' configuration and is very troublesome to set up.

How can I avoid having to set any environment variables?

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/intel_macsoft.html

related note for linux: [installing Oracle Instantclient on Linux without setting environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764871)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oracle's instantclient installation instructions specify that the user set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.  This is very troublesome to manage for multiple users.

To use the instantclient without setting any environment variables:

Download the instantclient distribution from oracle.com.  For doing non-java software development, you will need (assuming Oracle 10.2):

```
instantclient-basic-macosx-10.2.0.4.0.zip
instantclient-sdk-macosx-10.2.0.4.0.zip
instantclient-sqlplus-macosx-10.2.0.4.0.zip
```

Unzip the three files.  This will give you a directory

```
instantclient_10_2/
```

Copy the files to /usr, which is one of the default places the dynamic loader searches.

```
sudo cp instantclient_10_2/sdk/include/*.h /usr/include
sudo cp instantclient_10_2/sqlplus         /usr/bin
sudo cp instantclient_10_2/*.dylib         /usr/lib
```

If you use tnsnames.ora, copy it to /etc, which is the default global place the oracle runtime searches.

```
sudo cp tnsnames.ora /etc
```

Test with

```
/usr/bin/sqlplus scott/tiger@myoracle
```

Comment: This sounds great. But, I am trying to find where the downloads are available for the instantclient. Can't seem to find them.

Comment: Finally found the downloads location: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html

Comment: copying *.dylib is not enough. You must also copy *.dylib.10.1

Comment: Do not copy at least /PATH-TO-INSTANTCLIENT/sdk/include/ldap.h to /usr/include, that action will break you original ldap.h (OpenLDAP) file.

Comment: I'm on corporate Mac, I see that even if I've admin privileges, permission is denied to me. Any fixes?

Comment: @KrupalGhorpade, you will have to set the environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is simply to run sqlplus on your MacBook, this might work for you. Remove the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable from ~/.bashrc and replace it with an alias:

`alias sqlplus="DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/instantclient_11_2 sqlplus"`

[Blog entry: sqlplus and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS/X](https://blogs.oracle.com/taylor22/entry/sqlplus_and_dyld_library_path)

Answer (score 0):

After much research I found an sustainable solution to this error, that involves editing Apache's `launchd` configuration `.plist` file to specify the required `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `ORACLE_HOME`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables.

You can view the full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670810/1914455