# Proper way to set ORACLE_HOME?

Tags: oracle

On OS X should my ORACLE_HOME env variable be...

```
/usr/local/oracle
```

or...

```
/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_10_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to `/usr/local/oracle` and everything is working now. Don't know if that means `/usr/local/oracle` is necessarily correct.

Answer (score 3):

It should be set to the value of the directory that contains your \bin directory, which in your case I believe would be /usr/local/oracle/instantclient_10_2.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions here:

[installing Oracle Instantclient on Mac OS/X without setting environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684352/installing-oracle-instantclient-on-mac-os-x-without-setting-environment-variables)

you won't need to set any environment variables.  Its nice not to have to worry about it!