# Bash variable of name starting with 'DYLD' is not loaded into environment: bug or feature?

Tags: bash, oracle, macos, perl

On MacOs, try the following:

```
export AYLD_VARIABLE=Aa
export BYLD_VARIABLE=Bb
export CYLD_VARIABLE=Cc
export DYLD_VARIABLE=Dd
export EYLD_VARIABLE=Ee
export FYLD_VARIABLE=Ff
env | grep VARIABLE
```

The variable DYLD_VARIABLE is not displayed among others. It can not be exported.
However, it may be set and used:

```
   DYLD_VARIABLE=DdDd
   echo $DYLD_VARIABLE
```

It is just not present in env.
I know, MacOs uses the acronym 'DYLD' while speaking on some internal files. But this prefix should not be discriminated.

It is not just an academic issue. I failed to do

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/username/Downloads/instantclient_19_8
```

which is probably required to install DBD::Oracle for Perl.
How to set it up ?

Comment: See also [DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is not forwarded to external command in Makefile on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63629878/2173773)

Answer (score 7):

This is a feature of the hardened runtime environment. Several `DYLD_*` variables can be used to [inject malicious libraries into trusted binaries](https://theevilbit.github.io/posts/dyld_insert_libraries_dylib_injection_in_macos_osx_deep_dive/), so those variables are removed when a binary that uses the hardened runtime environment loads (unless it has the `com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables` or `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` entitlement).

I'm not familiar with how `DBD::Oracle` is set up, but if it depends on setting `DYLD_*` variables, it seriously needs to be rewritten to avoid that.

For more info, see [Apple's developer documentation on the hardened runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/hardened_runtime), and the WWDC19 presentation ["All About Notarization"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/703) (starting at 16:19, or page 75 of the slide deck).