# installing Oracle Instantclient on Linux without setting environment variables?

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, instantclient

Oracle's instructions specify setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  This makes my application dependent on random users' configuration and is very troublesome to set up.

How can I avoid having to set any environment variables?

related note for OS/X: [installing Oracle Instantclient on Mac OS/X without setting environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684352)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle's instantclient installation instructions specify that the user set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  This is very troublesome to manage for multiple users.

To use the instantclient without setting any environment variables:

Download the instantclient distribution from oracle.com.  For doing non-java software development, you will need (assuming Oracle 10.2):

```
instantclient-basic-linux-x86_64-10.2.0.4.0.zip
instantclient-sdk-linux-x86_64-10.2.0.4.0.zip
instantclient-sqlplus-linux-x86_64-10.2.0.4.0.zip
```

Unzip the three files.  This will give you a directory

```
instantclient_10_2/
```

Copy the files to /usr, which is one of the default places the dynamic loader searches.

```
sudo cp instantclient_10_2/sdk/include/*.h /usr/include
sudo cp instantclient_10_2/sqlplus         /usr/bin
sudo cp instantclient_10_2/*.so*           /usr/lib
```

If you use tnsnames.ora, copy it to /etc, which is the default global place the oracle runtime searches.

```
sudo cp tnsnames.ora /etc
```

Test with

```
/usr/bin/sqlplus scott/tiger@myoracle
```

Comment: I don't know that this is a great practice, but it does work!

Comment: This is a really bad practice.  Consider what you'll have to do when you need to upgrade.

Comment: So far, our upgrades have been simple... uninstall the old version of instantclient and install the new version of instantclient.  One tradeoff we have is that we're servicing a renderfarm with almost 15,000 cores, so eliminating potential problem areas such as incorrectly set environment variables is a big win for us.  Of course YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Add the library path to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, then run `/sbin/ldconfig`.  You don't need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for libraries installed in standard locations like `/usr/lib` because these locations are already configured in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Comment: I dont have ld.so.conf in etc folder and also I dont have ldconfig in sbin location. Totally struck!! what am I supposed to do now!?

Answer (score 3):

You could of course rename sqlplus to sqlplus.real and make a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "" ]
then
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/what/ever
else
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/what/ever
fi

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

exec sqlplus.real ${1+"$@"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's instructions regarding setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are suboptimal.

On ELF platforms like Linux or Solaris there is really no need to require setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because the correct library search path (a.k.a. runpath) can be written into the binary, at build-time, relative to the location of the binary. Thus, with such binaries, the runtime linker is always able to find the packaged libraries, even if the installed subtree is copied around.

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't create the Linux 'Instant Client' binaries like that. But, it is possible to fix them with [`patchelf`](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html).

For example:

```sh
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/..' /path/to/instantclient_11_2/sdk/proc
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN'    /path/to/instantclient_11_2/sqlplus
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN'    /path/to/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

After those changes the runtime linker is able to find all needed libraries without any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

On Solaris there is `elfedit` - but IIRC at least some Oracle DB packages for Solaris already come with a sufficient runpath. One can verify that via e.g. `elfdump /path/to/sqlplus | grep PATH`.

For more details on `elfedit` and other good alternatives to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (that don't involve changing the binary itself) see also my article [LD_LIBRARY_PATH considered harmful](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html).

Answer (score 1):

or you can try using this command

*Linux*

```
sqlplus user/pass@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port_number)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid)))'
```

*Windows*

```
sqlplus user/pass@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port_number)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid)))"
```

so you don't need the tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 0):

For anyone playing with Solaris (like me!) coming from a Linux background, I found that @David Phillips solution worked well using the Solaris command `crle -u -l /opt/instantclient`

Thanks to post http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/solaris/articles/ld-path-customisation-on-solaris/