# cx_oracle OSX install error

Tags: python, macos, oracle, cx-oracle, instantclient

So I followed these directions here to install Oracle InstantClient,

[installing Oracle Instantclient on Mac OS/X without setting environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684352/installing-oracle-instantclient-on-mac-os-x-without-setting-environment-variable)

But when I try to install cx_oracle I get the following stack trace,

```
python setup.py build
running build 
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6-10g
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/usr -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6-10g/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.1.1
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6-10g
gcc-4.2 -Wl,-F. -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6-10g/cx_Oracle.o -L/usr/lib -lclntsh -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6-10g/cx_Oracle.so -shared-libgcc
ld: library not found for -lclntsh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: library not found for -lclntsh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: library not found for -lclntsh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/5Q/5QMpI35VGumn0wxJwdndr-r4BJ+/-Tmp-//ccG0USbB.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did I miss something when I followed the InstantClient installation?

List of libs copied

```
bnnz10.dylib 
libociei.dylib 
libsqlplusic.dylib 
libclntsh.dylib.10.1 
libocci.dylib.10.1 
libocijdbc10.dylib 
libsqlplus.dylib
```

Comment: What files did you copy to /usr/lib - the list of *.dylib

Comment: bnnz10.dylib libociei.dylib libsqlplusic.dylib
libclntsh.dylib.10.1 libocci.dylib.10.1   libocijdbc10.dylib   libsqlplus.dylib

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have not got a clntsh library to link against

To fix this you need in /usr/lib to link libclntsh.dylib.10.1 to libclntsh.dylib and libocci.dylib.10.1 to libocci.dylib

Note that I don't have the oracle library and so cannot confirm this will be sufficient.

Comment: Had to do ln -s libclntsh.dylib.10.1 libclntsh.dylib And it worked fine, thanks! :)