# Issue installing Oracle SQL Developer on my MacBookPro - Am I missing a component?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had to recently re-install OS X on my MBP and am in the process of re-installing all of my apps. One app that worked just fine in the past, but is now giving me errors is Oracle SQL Developer and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am missing.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Downloaded and installed SQL Developer on my machine.
2. Downloaded the Instant Client related files - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html (I installed all of the 64 bit related stuff on this page - Im on a 64 bit machine), combined it into one folder and moved it my /usr folder using this guide: [installing Oracle Instantclient on Mac OS/X without setting environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684352/installing-oracle-instantclient-on-mac-os-x-without-setting-environment-variable)
3. I also installed this the JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
4. I also set up my TNSNames.ora file and copied it to my /etc folder (This is required on a mac)

**Here's my problem - If I attempt to connect to my Oracle instance using the above, it throws this error:**

*An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path
Vendor code 0*

This occurs whether I use basic or the TNS connection type.

So my question to my fellow developers is - Am I missing something in terms of the install above? I have tried googling for that particular error message and not found anything useful. At first glance, it seems like SQL Developer is looking for some file.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

***EDIT - The version of SQL Developer that I am trying to install is 3.1.07 and I am trying to connect to an 11G instance.***

Comment: Which version of the database?  Which version of SQL Developer?  You say you had this application working previously, but if you're downloading stuff afresh there is a good chance you're wrangling a different configuration. This matters a lot: Oracle do not do a good job of maintaining their software on Mac OSX.

Comment: Hi APC - I just edited my question to include that info. Basically I am trying to install SQL Developer 3.1.07 and am attempting to connecting to an 11g instance. I dont remember what version of SQL Developer I had previously, but the Oracle instance was 11g even when I could connect.

Comment: Have you had a look at Jeff Smith's guide "Install Oracle SQL Developer on OS X (Mountain Lion)"? http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/07/install-oracle-sql-developer-on-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced, and make sure Use OCI/Thick driver is un-checked.

[image: SQL Developer in Mac OS X]

Once done, try creating a connection and test. I also think you might be running an in-compatible version of Java in your newly installed OS X, so try installing JDK 1.6.0_11 or above, if the solution doesn't work.