# Setting up a connection to Oracle on Mac

Tags: database, oracle, terminal, connector

Trying to get connection to Oracle DB from my Mac.
I use this tutorial:
http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-mac-edition/b/weblog/archive/2013/07/02/setting-up-a-connection-to-oracle-on-your-mac.aspx

I've done till this command: **Sudo chgrp –R wheel /Library/Oracle**

When I try it gives me an error: *chgrp: –R: Invalid argument*

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why did you tag this with `java` if you are not using Java/JDBC?

Comment: Sorry I will use java/JDBC, but before I need to add tnsname.ora, i think. Actually I use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684352/installing-oracle-instantclient-on-mac-os-x-without-setting-environment-variable/684359#684359)

Comment: No you don't. When using JDBC you don't need an Oracle client at all. The only thing you need is a Java runtime and the JDBC driver (a .jar file)

Comment: Yesterday I've tried [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/) to connect using jdbc, but it gives me errors. That's why I thought I need to install oracle client

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at ja.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClsLoader.findCls(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadCls(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClsLoader.loadCls(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lg.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lg.Class.forName(Native Method)
 at java.lg.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
 at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:13)

Comment: Then apparently you have not added the driver properly. Please search this site and the internet. There are millions of answers to this problem.

Comment: OK, thank you, I will try, What I need is to get data from xml file and put in oracle database, what is better using oracle client or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with JDBC. I didn't use Oracle client.