# Connecting to an remote Oracle XE11 database using FireDac and OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, oracle, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

I made a small application that should connect to an remote Oracle database running inside a virutal machine (W8.1).

On a sucessfull connection a showmessage should popup.

I folled those steps to ensure my application is able to connect:
[installing Oracle Instantclient on Mac OS/X without setting environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684352/installing-oracle-instantclient-on-mac-os-x-without-setting-environment-variable)

The application uses FireDac's Oracle `FireDAC.Phys.Oracle` driver to connect and `TFDGUIxLoginDialog` to login.

[image: guianderror]

Nothing really special indeed:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FDConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Connected');
end;

procedure TForm1.FDConnection1Error(ASender: TObject;
  const AInitiator: IFDStanObject; var AException: Exception);
begin
  ShowMessage(AException.ToString);
end;
```

This is working fine and quick in Windows 8.1 and 10.

However in Mavericks i get the `OID generation failed` error as shown in the picture.

It doesn't matter if i use the VMs IP or DNS name to connect. It won't connect at all.

Oracle's SQL Developer is able to connect, tho.

The Oralce SQL Developer takes about 15 - 20s until it establishes a connection to the database.

My application isn't even trying that long to connect. It fails after ~7s.

Maybe it times out before a stable connection is available?

If so, is there any way to extend the login process time before throwing errors?

Or maybe this is a complete other problem?

Please note that i spent about 5 hours figuring out this problem already without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you edit your [hosts](http://chaos667.tumblr.com/post/20006357466/ora-21561-and-oracle-instant-client-11-2) file?

Comment: @whosrdaddy

It was one of the first things i did. 

But i entered the wrong hostname.

Your comment made me recheck the settings multiple times and i ended up finding out the correct one. Thanks again. Saved my day :)

I will post an answer on what went wrong shortly!

Comment: I'm glad you found your problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is what went wrong.

The host file of my OSX Mavericks guest system was incorrect.

Like @whosrdaddy posted you have to change your host file like explained in this link: http://chaos667.tumblr.com/post/20006357466/ora-21561-and-oracle-instant-client-11-2

I did enter the Devicename one can find in Sharing -> Devicename in the OSX Control Panel.

[image: osx control panel devicename]

So what i did was entering this name in the host file.

[image: osx hostfile]

However i was using the **incorrect name**.

I got the correct name by using `echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)` which printed the correct name: `127.0.0.1 LionVM.local`.

I didn't use this VM in a long time and probably forgotten that i renamed the devicename after upgrading to Mavericks some time ago.

Now my application is able to connect.